# Baum-Welch algorithm for pos tagger

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models, pos-tagger

everyone.
I'm using the Baum-Welch algorithm to train a pos tagger,it is totally in the unsupervised way.
Here comes the problem:
When i get the label result, I only get a sequence of numbers.
I can't figure out which label stands for VV,NN,DT.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What language are you tagging?

Comment: you should be getting probabilities for each word, and then you choose the one with the highest probability..

Comment: But i don't know which label stands for which pos tag. I only get 1 2 3 5 2 3

Answer (score 5):

In general, there's no way to do that.  Baum-Welch will find classes of word uses that have similar distributions, but there's no particular reason to suppose that those classes will map in any straightforward way to categories posited by any specific linguistic theory.  Therefore, unsupervised POS taggers are mainly useful for applications where you care about equivalence classes of words or phrases but not about the specific tags being assigned.

If you really need human-readable labels, though (e.g., during development, to evaluate whether the results you're getting are even remotely plausible), I'd hand-tag a few dozen sentences.  Then you could apply your B-W-derived tagger to that labeled mini-corpus to induce a mapping between class numbers and POS labels.

Comment: In my opinion,the unsupervised way seems not a good choice to create a useful pos tagger. Thank you for your explanation!!